# PHP Date String Format

Tags: php, cakephp, date

I have a string mm-dd-yyyy which i get from a form, which i want to store it in the database of the data-type DATE (yyyy-mm-dd).

How do i format the string and save it in the database ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$new_format = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('04-28-2012'));
```

or

```
$date = new DateTime('04-28-2012');
$new_format = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

or in PHP 5.5+

```
$new_format = (new DateTime('04-28-2012'))->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: i have the date in mm-dd-yyyy format string

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect this

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("m-d-Y", '02-15-2012');
echo  $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') , "\n";
```

Output

```
2012-02-15 23:54:52
```